# get values from the nested json in android and pass it to listview

Tags: android, json

i want to get the values from the below nested json string and pass it to listview, i'm confused about it. could somebody help it out from this problem.Thanks in advance

**JSON DATA :**

```
{
    "errstr": "Apps list",
    "success": 1,
    "data": {
        "topFree": [
            {
                "AppID": "3",
                "Title": "rgrger",
                "Price": null,
                "Rating": ""
            },
            {
                "AppID": "10",
                "Title": "dwdqw",
                "Price": null,
                "Rating": ""
            }
        ],
        "topPaid": [
            {
                "AppID": "14",
                "Title": "erfwerwe",
                "Price": "0.00",
                "Rating": ""
            }
        ],
        "magazine": [
            {
                "AppID": "65",
                "Title": "wdfwfqw",
                "Price": "0.00",
                "Rating": ""
            }
        ],
        "books": "",
        "onlineApp": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
try {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject data = result.getJSONObject("data");

    // check for your conditions... i am directly calling array now..

    if(data.has("topFree"){
        JSONArray array = data.getJSONArray("topFree");
        //creating array for storing values... you caN create with your class..
        arr_list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String AppID = ""+obj.getString("AppID");
            String Title = ""+obj.getString("Title");
            String Price = ""+obj.getString("Price");
            String Rating = ""+obj.getString("Rating");
            arr_list.add(AppID); // adding values to array.
        }
    }
   // do the same for other arrays

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After you get data.. you can add values to listview adapter..

Comment: Thanks for quick response, will check and let you know.

Comment: i can able to fetch the data, i need some suggestion, hope you will help it out, please see the image in the link.http://www.mediafire.com/view/g21kw66xlmhqqdt/Main_Screen.jpg

i want to set data in to that listview,it takes four different datas  in one row how to differentiate it.

Comment: Create a getter-setter class with 4 string variable(or relevant) and and assign it to array like `ArrayList<GETTERSETTER_CLASS>()` so you can get and set values from array..

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Parse JSONObject first, assuming that you have got this JSON as a response and you are unable to parse it.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(mJsonString);
// mJsonString is the json you have received as a response
String errstr = jsonObj.getString("errstr");
String success = jsonObj.getString("success");

String data = jsonObj.getString("data");

JSONObject jsonObjData = new JSONObject(data);
String topFree = jsonObjData.getString("topFree");

if(topFree != null){
   JSONArray mArray = new JSONArray(topFree);
   for(int i=0;i<mArray.length;i++){
     JSONObject mJsonObj = new JSONObject(
                                mArray.getString(i));
     String appId = mJsonObj.getString("AppID");
     String title = mJsonObj.getString("Title");
     String price = mJsonObj.getString("Price");
     String rating = mJsonObj.getString("Rating");

    }
String topPaid = jsonObjData.getString("topPaid");
if(topPaid != null){
   JSONArray mArrayTopPaid = new JSONArray(topPaid);
   for(int i=0;i<mArrayTopPaid.length;i++){
     JSONObject mJsonObj = new JSONObject(
                                mArrayTopPaid.getString(i));
     String appId = mJsonObj.getString("AppID");
     String title = mJsonObj.getString("Title");
     String price = mJsonObj.getString("Price");
     String rating = mJsonObj.getString("Rating");

    }
    String magazine = jsonObjData.getString("magazine");
   if(magazine != null){
   JSONArray mArrayMagazine = new JSONArray(magazine);
   for(int i=0;i<mArrayMagazine.length;i++){
     JSONObject mJsonObj = new JSONObject(
                                mArrayMagazine.getString(i));
     String appId = mJsonObj.getString("AppID");
     String title = mJsonObj.getString("Title");
     String price = mJsonObj.getString("Price");
     String rating = mJsonObj.getString("Rating");

    }
    String books = jsonObjData.getString("books");
    String onlineApp = jsonObjData.getString("onlineApp");

}
```