# How to set raw array in list using base adapter in android?

Tags: android, listadapter, arrays

I am developing an android application where I have an raw Jsonarray like -

```
[{"profilePic":"url","firstName":"Hitesh","lastName":"Matnani","status":0};   
{"profilePic":"url2","firstName":"Daljeet","lastName":"Singh","status":1}]
```

I have to use this Jsonarray in list Adapter which have an Image and an text.

Help me I am new to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing Change your JSON to

**JSON :**

```
[
    {
        "profilePic": "url",
        "firstName": "Hitesh",
        "lastName": "Matnani",
        "status": 0
    }, <-- remove semicolon(;) from here.. there must be comma (,)
    {
        "profilePic": "url2",
        "firstName": "Daljeet",
        "lastName": "Singh",
        "status": 1
    }
]
```

then store JSON TO VARIABLE as String and parse it like below.

**SOLUTION :**

```
try {
    String response = "YOUR JSON STRING";
    JSONArray result = new JSONArray (response);

        for (int i = 0; i < result .length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String profilePic= ""+obj.getString("profilePic");
            String firstName= ""+obj.getString("firstName");
            String lastName= ""+obj.getString("lastName");
            String status= ""+obj.getInt("status");

            // do code for adding these values to adapter.
        }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks and sorry the semi colon was written by me my mistake

Comment: its okay.. try this.. this may help you..

Comment: @Prag'sシ `:` -> Colon, `;` -> Semicolon, `,` -> Comma

Comment: After this I am adding this to my list adapter like -  ListAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(
       EditActivity.this, contactList,
       R.layout.list_item, new String[] { profilePic,firstName,lastName}, new int[] { R.id.name,R.id.email,R.id.mobile});
     setListAdapter(adapter1); but this is not working can you please help me in solving this

Comment: @Hitesh : visit this answer of me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524433/get-values-from-the-nested-json-in-android-and-pass-it-to-listview/27524638#27524638